# How to execute two different methods for when a checkbox is checked and unchecked in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a checkbox which sorts an array. I want it to sort the array when it is checked and revert back to the previous arrangement when it is unchecked. However, I only know how to execute the sorting method when the checkbox is checked and not when it is unchecked.

Here is my code for the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" @click="sortNew"> Newest First
```

and this is the method:

```
sortNew() {
      this.projects.sort((a,b) => b.id - a.id)
    }
```

Now, I want to execute the method below when it is unchecked:

```
sortOld() {
      this.projects.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
    }
```

So, how do I do it? I am using Vue.js 3.0.0.

Comment: Create new method where you can check value of checkbox is checked or unchecked based on that u can call either sortnew or sortold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to attach a `v-model` and a `@change` to the checkbox. The `@change` executes a function which checks whether the v-model is true or false and then follows an if-else statement to arrive at the desired result.

The final code looks something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" @change="sorter" v-model="sort"> Newest First

methods: {
    sorter() {
       if (this.sort) {
        // some code
      } else {
        // some code
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data property, something like `sort: true` and then use the single method to sort and unsort the array.

So whenever the sort is true, it will sort the array and then also set the sort to false, so whenever the next time the button is clicked, it will move to the else part and unsort the array, and then again set the sort to true and so on.

```
sortNew() {
    if (this.sort) {
        this.projects.sort((a,b) => b.id - a.id)
        this.sort = false;
    } else {
        this.projects.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
        this.sort = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just rewrite the code like,

```
 <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="decideFun($event)">

 decideFun(event) {
    if(event.target.checked){
       sortNew(this);
    }else{
       sortOld(this);}
 }

 sortNew(current) {
   current.projects.sort((a,b) => b.id - a.id)
 }

 sortOld(current) {
   current.projects.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
 }
```